# Convert multiple cumulative columns to normal form and plot in R

Tags: r, dataframe, graph

So I have a data frame of the following form represented in a very simple way:

| Sno | Box1 | Box2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 8 |
| 2 | 7 | 9 |
| 3 | 13 | 12 |

But it consists of 50 such boxes and 100 such serial numbers

Now I am facing two problems:

Firstly, I want to convert this cumulative data to normal data

| Sno | Box1 | Box2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 | 3 |

Secondly, I want to plot each of these columns in a graph. So the plot 1 will produce a graph for Box 1 with the SNo as the x-axis and the box 1 values as the y-axis. Similarly, plot 2 will produce a graph for Box 2 with the SNo as the x-axis and the box 2 values as the y-axis, and so on.

So the end result would be 50 graphs represented in a paper, which will show the data in a daily basis, using R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is (please provide code, not tables/ pictures)

```
df <- data.frame(Sno= 1:3, Box1= c(5,7,13), Box2= c(8,9,12))
```

We can simply use difference between rows to make it "normal" and not cumulative:

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(Sno= df$Sno,
                       rbind.data.frame(df[1, 2:ncol(df)],
                                        df[2:(nrow(df)), 2:ncol(df)] - 
                                        df[1:(nrow(df)-1), 2:ncol(df)])
                                        )
```

And you can plot all the columns like that:

```
for(col_i in names(df)[-1]){
  plot(df$Sno, df[ , col_i], ylab= col_i)
}
```

Comment: nice, I have already thought of this, but the problem is I have 50 such boxes and 100 such serial numbers. So writing this manually isn't  generic.

Comment: @Maharrnab This code is not "writting manually" because it accepts any number of columns and any number of rows. Try it.

Comment: I tried this just now, its showing the following error message: Error in df$Sno : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Sorry, I did one mistake in the structure of the data frame, so it was not working. This was exactly the thing I wanted, Thanks a lot :)